# How to create a Many to Many Relation in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I´m new in Django and I´ve been trying to create a Model, where I have many warehouses and many products. So far I have achieved this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  idProduct = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  quantity = models.IntegerField()


  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Warehouse(models.Model):
  idWareouse = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

But the problem is, that one product can be in multiple warehouses with different product quantity, and I don´t know how to model this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the attribute `through` of a `ManyToMany` relation. See [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

It would result in this :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    idProduct = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    idWareouse = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Catalog')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

See the `products` field in the `Warehouse` class :

`products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='Catalog')`

There is a [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the third model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    idProduct = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    idWareouse = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalogue(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) when you want to have a `many-to-many` relation with a custom intermediate table. The principle is to tell Django that there is a table for the `many-to-many` relation. And it is more precise since such a relation would be present. Here you are hiding the relation (in my opinion). [Example from the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)